# Set interruptionLevel in iOS notifications to support time-sensitive notifications on react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

iOS recently introduced "Focus modes" using which user can control interruptions when they are doing something. For e.g. user can configure a "Sleep" focus mode and a "Work" focus mode and specify which all apps can send notifications to the phone when the phone is on those focus modes. Apart from this, an app developer can mark some notifications as "time-sensitive" in which case the notifications are delivered even if the user is in a focus mode. The way to send time-sensitive notifications is to set an `interruptionLevel` on the notifications while scheduling them.

Is there a way to set the `interruptionLevel` on local notifications for iOS app built using react-native. I am using `https://github.com/react-native-push-notification/ios` to display notifications on iOS but didn't see any documentation that talks about showing time-sensitive notifications.

Comment: Hi dear @VarunGupta, what is a time-sensitive notification? what you expect from that library and it is failed? say your question a little clear. thanks.

Comment: I have added some more information about the time-sensitive notifications. I expect to be able to schedule time-sensitive notifications using the library.